# Do Articles 8 and 9 of EC261 not apply to flight cancellations announced 2+ weeks in advance?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, passenger-rights, ec261

Regarding the EC261 regulation, I know Article 7 (compensation) doesn't apply if the flight is cancelled more than two weeks in advance. However, it's always been my understanding that Article 8 (right to a **choice** between a refund and re-routing "at the earliest opportunity") and Article 9 (right to care) apply regardless, the latter provided I haven't opted for a refund.

However, the Irish national enforcement body just told me Article 8 and 9 don't apply either if the flight was cancelled two weeks or more in advance, and that I can only get a refund and am on my own in terms of getting home.

Is this really the case? Some clarification would be appreciated.

**UPDATE** Thankfully turned out only the phone representative was incompetent (which is bad enough!) The "Air Passenger Rights Manager" e-mailed me saying they'll log my case and that I should drop them a message if Ryanair rejects my claim for reimbursement for two rail tickets (I was originally going to book KLM to get home but went with Ryanair+rail)

Comment: The [plain language of Article 5](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32004R0261) backs up your understanding, and the [European Commission's interpretive guidelines](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/sites/transport/files/legislation/c20201830.pdf) (from March) confirm it as well.  It's possible there has been further guidance and/or rule changes since March, though.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Upon reading Article 5, the "unless" could be interpreted as covering 1(a-c), but I've always read it as only covering 1(c). Dear, could Mr. O'Leary actually have "bribed" the Irish NEB into scamming passengers!?